# Convert jQuery mobile application to apk

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I made a simple application in jQuery mobile annd HTML 5 according to the following tutorial ,

http://www.erikyuzwa.com/mobile/your-first-mobile-application-using-jquery-mobile-1-0-hello-world/

Any one please help me how to convert this application to and apk file, so that I can install it in my mobile using phone gap. I downloaded phone gap already

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need the Android SDK as well as PhoneGap.

This should get you going:

http://phonegap.com/start#android

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/creating-an-android-hello-world-application-with-phonegap/

Comment: can we not use jquery mobile without PhoneGap?

Comment: Not to make an APK. Plus, the OP specifically mentioned PhoneGap.

Answer (score 3):

If you have dreamviewer 5.5 IDE then it is so simple.
Just create new site in dreamveaver, and in Site menu, there is an option of Mobile Application.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/whats-new-dwcs55.html